# The system cannot find the path specified - batch to exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe

Good morning. I have written a batch file that updates the group policy via the audit.csv file. Previously I was changing the policy via `auditpol` but those changes didn't persist so I came up with this solution.

```
:: Write the correct audit settings to audit.csv
set "auditFile="C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Microsoft\Windows NT\Audit\audit.csv""

echo Machine Name,Policy Target,Subcategory,Subcategory GUID,Inclusion Setting,Exclusion Setting,Setting Value > %auditFile%
echo ,System,Audit Credential Validation,{0cce923f-69ae-11d9-bed3-505054503030},Success and Failure,,3 >> %auditFile%
…
```

It does some other stuff, but that's where I'm getting the error.

Yesterday, running this just as a regular batch script file worked fine. Now I'm getting the `The system cannot find the path specified.` error. I have seen a few posts with the same problem and the solution was to run `cmd /c file.bat` which isn't working for me right now. When creating the post, I wasn't expecting to have this problem running the batch file. When I tested yesterday, the batch file worked fine, but when I converted to an exe (both with PowerArchiver and iexpress) is when I got the error. So I don't know why it's not working in the .bat version, but I guess if I can fix this it should fix the converted exe.

My main question is why am I getting that error? Is it because of the echo command? Is it giving me the error because of the file I'm trying to access? Is it a permissions thing?

Comment: Do not place your batch file inside an extractable package, just keep it exactly as it should be, and you know works. And I would have used **1.** `(Echo Machine Name,Policy Target,Subcategory,Subcategory GUID,Inclusion Setting,Exclusion Setting,Setting Value`
**2.** `Echo ,System,Audit Credential Validation,{0cce923f-69ae-11d9-bed3-505054503030},Success and Failure,,3) 1> "%auditFile%"` if I believed that each line would be read wrapped over multiple lines like that.

Comment: I don't have a choice about packaging it up in an exe. I'll try your suggestion though

Comment: Yes you do, if they want an`.exe` file, write an `.exe` file.

Comment: Do NOT include the extra set of quotes in the variable assignment. The proper syntax for defining a variable is: `set "var=value"`. Then when using that variable you would do this: `echo some thing>"%var%"`.

Answer (score 0):

The batch file is executed by 64-bit `cmd.exe` stored in `%SystemRoot%\System32` on double clicking on the batch file with **Windows File Explorer**. The directory `%SystemRoot%\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Microsoft\Windows NT\Audit` exists most likely in this case (not on my Windows computers).

But after packing the batch file into a 32-bit executable file which extracts it on execution into `%TEMP%` or a temporarily created subdirectory in `%TEMP%` and next runs Windows command processor for execution of the temporarily extracted batch file, the 32-bit `cmd.exe` stored in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` is executed because of Windows [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

The file system redirector active in execution environment of x86 applications redirects the write access to file `%SystemRoot%\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Microsoft\Windows NT\Audit\audit.csv` now to `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\GroupPolicy\Machine\Microsoft\Windows NT\Audit\audit.csv` and most likely the entire directory tree for file `audit.csv` does not exist in this case.

A solution would be using this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define Windows system folder path and make sure the right path is used
rem if this batch file is executed on 64-bit Windows in 32-bit environment.
set "SystemFolder=%SystemRoot%\System32"
if not "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe set "SystemFolder=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative"
set "AuditFilePath=%SystemFolder%\GroupPolicy\Machine\Microsoft\Windows NT\Audit"

rem Create the directory with suppressing the error message on missing
rem permissions to create this directory or on directory existing already.
md "%AuditFilePath%" 2>nul
if not exist "%AuditFilePath%\" (
    echo ERROR: Failed to creeate the directory:
    echo        %SystemRoot%\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Microsoft\Windows NT\Audit
    echo        The batch file "%~nx0" must be run as administrator.
    goto EndBatch
)

rem Write the correct audit settings to file audit.csv.
set "FullAuditFileName=%AuditFilePath%\audit.csv"
(
echo Machine Name,Policy Target,Subcategory,Subcategory GUID,Inclusion Setting,Exclusion Setting,Setting Value
echo ,System,Audit Credential Validation,{0cce923f-69ae-11d9-bed3-505054503030},Success and Failure,,3
) >"%FullAuditFileName%"

rem More commands to execute.

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

This batch file also creates the file `audit.csv` with the two CSV lines without a trailing space at end of both lines.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~nx0` ... name + extension of batch file
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- Microsoft documentation about [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details)
- Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))